# Inherited Value in Column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

we have a wpf-window with some textboxes and a datagrid.
the textboxes descripe a parent (class a) object and the datagrid lists a collection of "childs" (class b => not derived from class a).
the childs can inherit values from the parent.

for example if the parent (class a) has a property Foo then the child object (class b) has a property Nullable which can either override the value of the parent or inherit the value of the parent.

now the datagrid should display the value in gray (if it is inherited) or in black (if the user overrides the value in the grid cell).

Unfortunatly Binding to InheritedText doesnt work. Does someone have any idea?

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <UserControls:InheritedTextBoxControl 
                 Text="{Binding Path=?}"
                 InheritedText="{Binding Path=?}" />
      </DataTemplate>
 </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Thanks in advance
Tobi

--UPDATE--

xaml of InheritedTextBoxControl:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Com.QueoMedia.CO2Simulationstool.WPF.Utils.UserControls.InheritedTextBoxControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         Width="Auto"
         Height="Auto"
         Name="cnt">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="White">
    <TextBox TextChanged="TextBoxTextChanged"></TextBox>
    <TextBlock Name="inheritedText"
               IsHitTestVisible="False"
               Margin="4,0"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Opacity="0.5"
               FontStyle="Italic"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

CodeBehind:

```
public partial class InheritedTextBoxControl : UserControl {

    private bool _isInherited;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty InheritedTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("InheritedText", typeof(String), typeof(InheritedTextBoxControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));
    public static DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(InheritedTextBoxControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(string)));

    public InheritedTextBoxControl() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string InheritedText {
        get { return (string)GetValue(InheritedTextProperty); }
        set {
            SetValue(InheritedTextProperty, value);
            inheritedText.Text = value;
        }
    }

    private bool IsInherited {
        get { return _isInherited; }
        set {
            _isInherited = value;
            if (value) {
                inheritedText.Opacity = 0.5;
            } else {
                inheritedText.Opacity = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public string Text {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    private void TextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length > 0) {
            IsInherited = false;

        } else {
            IsInherited = true;
        }
        Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any binding error message in Visual Studio's output window during debugging? Please post the relevant parts of InheritedTextBoxControl, especially the definition of the InheritedText property.

Comment: There are no binding error messages.
Code of Control added!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested in the solution:

we did it using a CellTemplate containing a CustomControl name MaskedTextbox that has three properties (MaskedText, Text, IsMaskTextVisible) and a CellEditingTemplate to override the data.

The values are bound to an InheritableValueViewModel.

Tobi

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the setter of your `InheritedText` property. WPF won't call this setter when the property is set from XAML. See [Checklist for Defining a Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx#checklist), section *Implementing the "Wrapper"* for details.

You will have to update `inheritedText.Text` in a [PropertyChangedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx) like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty InheritedTextProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "InheritedText", typeof(string), typeof(InheritedTextBoxControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, InheritedTextChanged));   

private static void InheritedTextChanged(
    DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((InheritedTextBoxControl)d).inheritedText.Text = (string)e.NewValue;
}

public string InheritedText
{ 
    get { return (string)GetValue(InheritedTextProperty); } 
    set { SetValue(InheritedTextProperty, value); } // only call SetValue here
}
```

Comment: i tried it like this but it didnt work.
How should the binding look like?

Comment: A binding that works for `Text` should also work for `InheritedText`. Why did it not work what you tried? Didn't the PropertyChangedCallback get called?

Comment: No, the Callback didnt get called.

Comment: Is it called when you don't use a binding, e.g. when you set `InheritedText="Some Text"` or so? What does the binding look like?

Comment: I played around and the bindings looks like:

<UserControls:InheritedTextBoxControl Text="{Binding Path=IndividualMeasurePotential.Co2Potential.Value}"
                                                                  InheritedText="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=MeasureData:MeasureEditViewModel, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=DataContext.Co2Potential}"
                                                                  />

Comment: And does the InheritedText binding work on the Text property?